# Optical filters cascaded

Tags: optics, visible-light

I was wondering how I can calculate the transmission curve of two (or more) cascaded optical filters - it would be rather intuitive to simply multiply the individual curves, but does this represent physical reality?

Comment: Why would it not represent physical reality (barring interference effects)?

Comment: So, for an optical train like atmosphere - telescope - filter - detector, we get the overall transmission by multiplication of the individual components' transmission curves?

Comment: @JonCuster If you cascade filters with significant reflection your total throughput is not the product of individual transmissions. It is somewhat higher.

Comment: @Matt  - correct, that is an interference effect...

Comment: Someone claimed two filters 'in series' result in a transmission which is the convolution of the individual filter curves but I think it is just a simple multiplication -- so far I could not come up with literature to support either claim.